# Interface inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

As part of code refactoring, I have found some code duplicates that I'm trying to remove

I have an interface like one below, in an assembly I cannot modify.

```
public interface IArtifact
{
    void Accept(IArtifactVisitor visitor);
}

public  interface IArtifactVisitor
{
    void Visit(Topic topic);
}
```

In the references assembly, which I want to reuse existing interfaces there is the same function signature

```
public interface IArtifact
{
    void Accept(IArtifactVisitor visitor);
}

public  interface IArtifactVisitor
{
     void Visit(Topic topic);
     void Visit(NewTopic topic);
}
```

and the Accept looks something like this

```
public void Accept(IArtifactVisitor visitor)
{
    visitor.Visit(this);
}
```

In order to removed the code reuse, I have tried the following:

```
public interface MyIArtifact : IArtifact
{
    void Accept(MyIArtifactVisitor visitor);
}

public interface MyIArtifactVisitor : IArtifactVisitor
{
    void Visit(NewTopic topic);
}
```

but what this does is, it forces me in each implementation class to implement both Accept(MyIArtifactVisitor visitor) and Accept(IArtifactVisitor visitor)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can create a common base (abstract or not) class that implements these interfaces and inherit from that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to do.  What code duplication do you currently have other than the "duplicate" interfaces in referenced assemblies(which you can't really do much about)

Comment: This is an example of pattern that is repeated , for example void Visit(Topic topic) is duplicated , across interfaces

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler  Well, if they're both in assemblies which you can't change, there's not anything you can do about it

Comment: I can change only the new assembly, the one that implements void Visit(NewTopic topic);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visitor pattern is screwed up, and IMHO it is non-sense to implement it through interfaces. The way you implement visitor pattern is as follows:

```
abstract class Artifact{
     internal abstract void Visit(ArtifactVisitor visitor);
}


class Topic : Artifact{
     internal override void Visit(ArtifactVisitor visitor)
     {
        visitor.Visit(this);
     }
}

class ArtifactVisitor{
    internal virtual void Visit(Artifact artifact)
    {
        artifact.Visit(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Visit(Topic topic)
    {
    }
}

class SomeSpecificTopicVisitor : ArtifactVisitor
{
     protected override void Visit(Topic topic)
     {
         //do something with topics
     }     
}
```

From this state, you can start inheriting your own visitors from ArtifactVisitor. You will only override the methods which you actually need.

The visitor pattern is not very extensible. It is only useful if the set of inheritors is fixed and will not change significantly. Nevertheless, if you use it properly, it will nicely solve your double dispatching problems.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you only need to specify one method signature in your interface

```
public interface MyIArtifactVisitor : IArtifactVisitor
{
     void Visit(NewTopic topic);
}
```

And that's essentially it.  So, if you want to impliment that, and the external interface, then you do something like the following

```
public class MyImplimentingClass : MyIArtifactVisitor, IArtifactVisitor 
{
     public void Visit(NewTopic topic)
     {}

     public void Visit(Topic topic)
     {}
}
```